# Change Twilio Authy OTP expiration time

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

How can I set the expiration time for twilio's authy OTP sent via SMS. I don't see how to change the default expiration time anywhere in the docs. I would like the OTP to remain valid for 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid you cannot change the expiration time for the OTP with Authy.

30 minutes seems like a riskier length of time to allow for one token to be active. There is some drift with tokens, you don't need to enter it within 30 seconds, but half an hour is not among any recommended lengths of token expiration time.

Comment: I would like to know the length of the "drift" you mentioned. 
I noticed that a script of mine worked even after the OTP dissapeared from my cellphone.
It was the case when I needed to manually enter a password *after* having entered the OTP.

Comment: @JuanLanus I don't actually know how much time the Auth API gives in terms of drift. But it's normally the case that at least one window of time beyond the time the code is showing is acceptable. [This Node.js library makes the default window 50 periods](https://github.com/guyht/notp/blob/master/index.js#L112) and [the default on this Ruby library is 0 periods](https://github.com/mdp/rotp/blob/master/lib/rotp/totp.rb#L39). It really depends on the application's implementation.